# What does "WARNING: Could not create empty movie file container" mean in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, codec

I'm following a OpenCV book's tutorial and the following code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string arg1 = "new.mov";
    string arg2 = "mov.mov";
    CvCapture* capture = 0;
    capture = cvCreateFileCapture(arg1.c_str());
    if(!capture){
        return -1;
    }
    IplImage *bgr_frame=cvQueryFrame(capture);
    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty (
            capture,
            CV_CAP_PROP_FPS
    );
    CvSize size = cvSize(
            (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),
            (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    );
    CvVideoWriter* writer = cvCreateVideoWriter(
        arg2.c_str(),
        CV_FOURCC('N', 'T', 'S', 'C'),
        fps,
        size
    );
    IplImage* logpolar_frame = cvCreateImage(
            size,
            IPL_DEPTH_8U,
            3
    );
    while((bgr_frame=cvQueryFrame(capture)) != NULL){
        cvLogPolar(
                bgr_frame, logpolar_frame,
                cvPoint2D32f(bgr_frame->width/2, bgr_frame->height/2),
                40,
                CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS
                );
                cvWriteFrame(writer, logpolar_frame);
    }
    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
    cvReleaseImage(&logpolar_frame);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't give me an error when I run the code - instead the program outputs to the console:

```
WARNING: Could not create empty movie file container.
```

Followed by 100 or so lines of:

```
Didn't successfully update movie file.
```

What does this error (or whatever it's called) mean and what's causing it?

I don't know if this helps, but it used to give me an error about the codec (which in the book was MJPG) so I changed `CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')` to `CV_FOURCC('N', 'T', 'S', 'C')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `CV_FOURCC('N', 'T', 'S', 'C')` to `CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X')`. Here's [manual](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html) for you.

Possible codecs:

```
CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1')    = MPEG-1 codec
CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')    = motion-jpeg codec (does not work well)
CV_FOURCC('M', 'P', '4', '2') = MPEG-4.2 codec
CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', '3') = MPEG-4.3 codec
CV_FOURCC('D', 'I', 'V', 'X') = MPEG-4 codec
CV_FOURCC('U', '2', '6', '3') = H263 codec
CV_FOURCC('I', '2', '6', '3') = H263I codec
CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1') = FLV1 codec
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. I tried DivX before, but I forgot to capitalize it.

Answer (score 2):

NTSC isn't a valid codec fourcc so no video writer is being created

Comment: Thanks. I really don't understand codecs. What should I use instead?

Answer (score 1):

Came looking for solution to same message. In my case I use Mac/OSX and I DID use CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'). It came out that it failed when output file ended with ".mp4" and worked with ".avi".